# Finding extremum value of multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How can I find the max and min values of $$f(x,y)=2x^2y-3xy^2+36xy$$ *on* and *in* the triangular region with vertices $(-14,-2), (0,-2), (0,12)$?

I have graphed the triangular region and calculated
$$f_x(x,y)=4xy-3y^2+36y$$
$$f_y(x,y)=2x^2-6xy+36x$$

I do not know how to continue.

Note: this is a homework question, with explicit permission to "discuss ideas"

**Edit**: Forgot to add that I have found the critical points to be $(0,0),(0,12),(-6,4),(-18,0)$

Comment: To find max/min inside the triangle, you have to find the critical points by equating $f_x=0$ and $f_y=0$ and then see which of these lie inside the triangle.

Comment: Does any point lie inside the triangle?

Comment: @PJK (0,0) and (0,12) are on the triangle's edge. (-6,4) is in the triangle. (-18,0) is outside the triangle and can be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already noted, $(0, 0), (18, 0), (0, 12)$ and $(-6, 4)$ are the critical points of which only $(-6, 4)$ lies inside the triangle with $\color{blue}{f(-6, 4)=-288}$. So this point $(-6, 4)$ is one candidate for global max or min.

Now for the boundary of the triangular region, we look for the possible max/min at each of the three straight lines bounding the triangle. For example, lets consider the side joining $(-14, -2)$ and $(0, -2)$. The equation of this line is $y=-2$ and so the function $f(x, y)$ reduces to $$f(x, -2)=-4x^2-12x-72x=-4x^2-84x$$ with  $-14\leq x\leq 0$ on this line. This is a single variable function with critical point $x=-\frac{21}{2}$ which lies within $-14\leq x\leq 0$. So the point $(-\frac{21}{2}, -2)$ is one candidate for global max/min on this edge of the triangle with $\color{blue}{f(-\frac{21}{2}, -2)=441}$. Also on the two boundary points $(-14, -2)$ and $(0, 2)$ of this line, we have $\color{blue}{f(-14, -2)=392}$ and $\color{blue}{f(0, 2)=0}$.

Proceed similarly for the other two sides and then find the global max or min by comparing all the possible candidates (colored in blue).

Comment: I'm getting f(-10.5,-2) = 441. Also, how do you know that they will be *global* min/max rather than *local* min/max?

Comment: Also, are there any (infinitely many?) critical points for the line $x=0, -2 \le x \le 12$?

Comment: Sorry, my calculation was wrong. All the local min/max are also candidates for the global min/max but we also have to compare them with the local min/max that can occur on the boundary. Its just like when you have to find the global min/max of $f(x)$ on $[a, b]$, we first find the function value on critical points inside the interval $(a, b)$, and on the boundaries $a$,and $b$ and then compare them. No not all points on $x=0$ are critical points of $f$ as $f_x$ may not be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

As PJK commented, the first thing to do is to write
$$f_x(x,y)=4xy-3y^2+36y=y(4x-3y+36)=0 \tag 1$$
$$f_y(x,y)=2x^2-6xy+36x=x(2x-6y+36)=0 \tag 2$$

Now, from$(2)$, $y=6+\frac x 3$. Plug it in $(2)$ to get $$x^2+24 x+108=(x+6)(x+18)=0 \tag 3$$ So , the solutions are $(x_1=-18,y_1=0)$,  $(x_2=-6,y_2=4)$. But $(x_3=0,y_3=0)$ is also a solution as well as $(x_4=0,y_4=12)$.

Now compare with the triangle to see the solutions to be retained and, for these, compute $f(x,y)$.